# Where to find Ironpython language reference explaining ".As" assignment?

Tags: ironpython, spotfire, tibco

I'm trying to learn Ironpython for Spotfire.
I can see a lot of assignments like a=b.as[ ] which use the ".As" method, for example:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import Visualization

for page in Document.Pages:
    for vis in page.Visuals:
        myvis = vis.As[Visualization]()
```

I more or less know what's going on but where can I find some language reference explaining in full how these assignments work and what the syntax is? Particularly the ".As" thing.

Many thanks

Comment: The syntax of Python, as well as how assignments work, is explained here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html

Comment: I'm assuming you want to know that the `As` attribute of the `vis` object does? Then you would need to look up the documentation for `Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals.Visualization` (which has less to do with the syntax of Python). You find it here: https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/spotfire/7.9.0/TIB_sfire-analyst_7.9.0_api/html/T_Spotfire_Dxp_Application_Visuals_Visualization.htm

Comment: @mkrieger1 The thing is I cannot see where "As" is mentioned, hence the q. Can't search for it ... I assume if you know the language syntax by heart it is easy for you to find it, but I can't..

Comment: Oh, I just found out that I was misleading you, sorry. You would need to look up the documentation for whatever `page.Visuals` returns when being iterated over. `vis` is not necessarily a `Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals.Visualization` object like I first thought. However, since I don't know what `page` is, I can't tell you what `vis` is.

Comment: @mkrieger1 thanks for helping me! In Spotfire a Page is equivalent to a tab in a browser and there may be a collection  of visualisations on each page. You can iterate across this collection.

Comment: So... it appears this '.As[class]()' method is sort of 'casting' an object into a different class ...well apparently. 
Still, can't see any documentation describing in detail how this works, apart a one liner in Spotfire API doc which is pretty much pointless.